# Is there some regulation/building code/specification to gives such exact dimensions?

Tags: building-regulations

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=62)

> most
>   electrical panels in installation are 15
>   inches, so that they fit tight in between
>   studs ...

and showing this illustration

[image]

The parts pointed out by red arrows are 2 studs, between which is a electrical panel.

Per his talking, the electrical panel has a width of 15 inches, strictly that should be 14½ inches.

So, is there some regulation or building code to gives such exact dimensions?

I googled and got [this](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Eco0Xp3RHq3az7sP4u6AkAs&q=electrical%20panels%20dimension%2015%20inches&oq=electrical%20panels%20dimension%2015%20inches&gs_l=psy-ab.3...260.5453..5612...0.2..0.241.1594.0j9j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i22i29i30j33i160.5pc4z4gmlpw&ved=0ahUKEwjdncaCkK_nAhUt7XMBHWI3ALIQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), posts about how many watt.

Comment: What tutorial? Anyway, in the US (and probably elsewhere) standard framing is 16" stud-to-stud ("on center"). There will be plenty of stud bays of smaller dimension, and occasional ones larger as long as the loads are properly distributed, but sizing the box to the standard gap between studs provides for the most common case. As far as 15" vs 14.5" goes, the tutorial could just be rounding, or the box could have a flange that extends over each stud on the left and right. Not enough detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

For each manufacturer,  there are *maybe* a dozen sizes of panel box, into which they put all their innards and covers.    You can look them up in the manufacturer's catalog:

[Square D](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Catalog&p_File_Name=0100CT1901_SEC-01.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=0100CT1901_SEC-01) or [Siemens/Murray](https://www.downloads.siemens.com/download-center/Download.aspx?pos=download&fct=getasset&id1=BTLV_39296) or [GE](https://electrification.us.abb.com/catalog/buylog/GE%20Products%20BuyLog%202019/01_GE%20Products%20BuyLog_LoadCtrCircBreak.pdf) or [Eaton](https://www.eaton.com/ecm/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&allowInterrupt=1&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased&Rendition=Primary&dDocName=CA08100002E)

When you read the catalog, you'll see each panel doesn't specify dimensions, but states a box size such as R-1.  Then you go to a page in the catalog that lists all the box dimensions.  It'll say R-1 -- 28.5" x 14.25" x 3.25" or whatever.

But you can easily scan down the table of *all* the box dimensions, and most of them - and all the larger ones - are ~14.5" wide.   Why?  **Because that is the standard space between joists**.

They used to make narrower boxes, e.g. 9" or 11" wide, but those were eliminated due to the wire bending space rules.  Now, to get into the gory details, here's how that went.

People at NFPA said "People are ordering bigger services with bigger wires now.  "These 11 inch wide panels won't do, because bigger wires need bending space. We want more like 15-16".
Builders pushed back and said "It's not your place to specify a number.  We don't like that number anyway.  A good number for us varies by application."
Manufacturers said "We can build anything you two want."
UL said "We can take care of this.  NFPA, you specify the bending radius requirements in NEC, we'll figure out what we're willing to approve in a panel, and communicate those requirements back to the manufacturer in the White Book. We and our competitors like ETL and CSA will approve based on the White Book."
NFPA said "Works for us.  We'd like X bending space."
Manufacturers said "Then most panels will be 15.5" or wider. Our customers won't like that."
Builders said "We sure won't. Standard joist spacing is 16" minus 1.5" for joist width minus 1/4-1/2" for tolerances.  How about 14 inches".
UL said "That would mean you'd need to change bending space to Y."
Manufacturers: "Y works for us."
NFPA said "We can live with that. Bending space is Y as of 19xx NEC."
UL said "Revising White Book accordingly".
Manufacturers said "OK builders, how wide do you want  your panels?"
Builders said "11 inches.  But we'll take 14-1/4."
Manufacturers consult White Book and say "We can build that."
Actual Government says "If NFPA says it's OK, it's OK with us. Rubberstamp!"

Comment: I googled `panel box r-1 regulation/building code/specification 28.5" x 14.5" x 3.25"` and got some results, none of them links to "R-1". I've also searched a doc from [this link](http://www.floridabuilding.org/fbc/thecode/supplement/Building/Florida_supplement_to_2009IBC_with_recmendfinalfiling-combined2.doc) and didn't find the regulation/building code/specification about a panel box. Would you please provide a source.

Comment: @zghqh there you go, but I don't think you understood what I was saying. You seem to be still pursuing your belief that these widths are handed down from some government agency.  I am not saying that at all. Also turns out it was 1-R not R-1.

Comment: @zghqh To expand on the last paragraph of Harper's answer, the NEC and Listing agencies (UL, ETL, CSA) work together to make sure their rules don't conflict. Wire maker submits wire specs to testing lab claiming bending radius that is a multiple of wire size is safe. UL tests and "Lists". NEC responds by making that bending radius a code item, panel makers determine largest size wire that would normally be used for a specific amperage panel, and the radius needed to enter the bottom and bend to terminate at the top. For buyer convenience they expand size to standard construction dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

There are no exact specifications on panel width. some are 15.4", some might be 14.75". The builders know the panels they'll be installing and frame the studs accordingly, maybe sistering an additional one if needed.